# How can I prevent an Explorer dialog disappearing the app from the task switcher?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Many Explorer dialogs like the one you see in the following picture

[image]

cause Explorer to disappear from the task switcher

[image: http://i.imgur.com/e0eDHEp.png].

This is particularly time wasting when I have many explorer windows. Is there any OS config change that will remedy this?

EDIT: The above example has info added by an additional program - dBpoweramp. Here is an example which apparently does not have added info:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EcBiC2z.png]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't even look like a standard windows dialog message  that is likely the reason

Comment: I think what you mean is that Explorer keeps crashing due to "file in use" errors. That's odd. I haven't seen that before (the crashing due to file in use). You can use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to unlock files in use.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think that dialog is unusual. It's probably like that because the OP has dbPowerAmp installed.

Comment: Can you give another example that isn't related to dBPowerAmp or another 3rd party software?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, Thanks for the suggestion. Now done.

Comment: @Vinayak, "I think what you mean is that Explorer keeps crashing due to "file in use" errors." No, that's not what I mean. And this is not a crash.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I don't think I fully understand what's happening here. When you say Explorer is missing from the taskbar, do you mean all your open folders are missing? Could you maybe record the screen using [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) and add a GIF to your question?

Comment: @Vinayak, Thanks, but I did not say "Explorer is missing from the taskbar". Please reread the question.

Comment: @ChrisJJ It still doesn't really make much sense. A GIF of this actually happening would help clarify the problem. Please add one.

Comment: You have a GIF of it happening. Two, in fact. To clarify, by disaapear, I mean the icon is absent whereas normally (without a dialog) it is present. The pictures show it absent. Here's what an Explorer icon on the task switcher looks like when it is present: http://i.imgur.com/b6yF4M9.png

Comment: @ChrisJJ By GIF, what I meant was an animated GIF where we can see the problem actually occurring. Anyway that won't be necessary because from the screenshot you posted in your comment, it is clear that Explorer is crashing. You can restart explorer by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ESC and then create a new task from the File menu, enter `explorer` and press OK. However, to actually figure out what might be causing Explorer to crash, I'll need more specifics. I suspect that the problem might have something to do with a rogue [shell extension](http://goo.gl/QGWxZg).

Comment: "from the screenshot you posted in your comment, it is clear that Explorer is crashing." How so? The Explorer window is present and responsive, and when I dismiss the dialog, Explorer continues fine.